# Building a jar using gradle dependencies?

Tags: android, maven, ant, gradle, build

I need to use following dependencies for android

eg:  compile 'com.github.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:v0.7.0*'

I can use these dependencies in android studio without any problem.But I need to make a jar file from the above dependencies without using android studio.

Is it Possible to build a jar file by using the  Ubuntu terminal or some other build tools like maven or  ant ?